# Cannot restart unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

I have a unicorn + nginx setup and suddenly when I run `cap unicorn:upgrade` (which sends a `USR2` to the master process) it doesn't prefix the .pid file and it doesn't fork a new master process at all. When I open the log file I can see the line

```
reaped #<Process::Status: pid 32448 exit 10> exec()-ed
```

can anyone suggest something to do in order to see what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your unicorn config have `preload_app(true)` ? You may need to send a QUIT signal if it does.